# Lagrange multipliers to show triangles are inscribed

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Use Lagrange multipliers to show that, of all the triangles inscribed in a circle of radius R, the equilateral triangle has the largest perimeter.

Not sure how to answer this question!

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As an alternative solution, I recommend you draw a picture with rays from the origin to the vertices of your triangle and use as your variables the three angles they form. Much easier and more intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The side lengths of a triangle are always given by numbers of the form $x+y,x+z,y+z$ with $x,y,z>0$ (this is also known as Ravi's substitution). By Heron's formula the area of a triangle in terms of $x,y,z$ is given by $\sqrt{xyz(x+y+z)}$, the perimeter by $2(x+y+z)$. By Euler's formula the circumradius $R$ is given by
$$ R=\frac{abc}{4\Delta}=\frac{(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)}{4\sqrt{xyz(x+y+z)}} $$
hence your problem can be written as
$$ \max_{\substack{x,y,z>0,\\\frac{(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)}{4\sqrt{xyz(x+y+z)}}=R}}2(x+y+z) $$
or as (dual form)
$$ \max_{\substack{x,y,z>0\\x+y+z=p}}\frac{(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)}{\sqrt{xyz}} $$

and solved through Lagrange's multipliers, but that is clearly an overkill. The maximum perimeter is attained when $\frac{(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)}{\sqrt{xyz}}$ reaches its maximum value. By the AM-GM (or Cauchy-Schwarz) inequality that happens only at $x=y=z$ and we are done.

Comment: Thanks Jack, that makes much more sense!